# Remove a random object from an array and return it

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to retrieve a random object from an array of objects, return that object, and also remove the object from the array. My code this fine, but I bet there's a far more neat manner to do it. Here's my version:

```
let deck = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
function returnCard(deck) {
  let element = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)];
  removeCard(element);
  return element;
}
function removeCard(card) {
  deck = deck.filter(function(el) {
    return el.name !== card.name;
  });
}
```

This looks verbose. I think part of what I'm struggling with is that I want to return, or reassign two things at once, the card and the deck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to delete elements from an array. This method also happens to return the deleted elements as an array; if you only delete a single element, you can access index `0` on the return value to in essence "pop" a single random element from a list.

```js
function popRandom (array) {
  let i = (Math.random() * array.length) | 0
  return array.splice(i, 1)[0]
}

let array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

console.log(popRandom(array))
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries, you should check out the Lodash _.remove function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(array);
// => [1, 3]

console.log(evens);
// => [2, 4]
```

Comment: I'd like to use lodash at some point, but for now I think vanilla works fine.